# How to assign and display a value inside of an AngularJS interpolation statement

Tags: angularjs

How can I assign and display the value of result in the code block below?

```
<div>{{result = valueA + valueB}}</div>

...


<div>{{result/ valueB}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-init in your first div to set the value of result.

```
<div ng-init="result = valueA + valueB">{{result}}</div>
...  
<div>{{result/ valueB}}</div>
```

Comment: I found that result = valueA + valueB does display the value of result